# GraphQL - Security - Protect nested data

Tags: security, nested, graphql, apollo, resolver

Let's assume my app is an e-commerce. There are `Users`, `Orders` and `Products`.

You need to be authenticated (with JWT Token) to have access to your `user` data, and your `orders`. This check is done in resolvers.

However, `Products` are public. You can see products without being logged in.

Of course, a `User` has `Orders`, and an `Order` has `Products`

What if someone in the frontend is doing this query:

```
query IAmEvil {
  products {
    orders {
      users {
         id
         name
         email
       }
    }
  }
}
```

This guy, not authenticated will have access to `users` data. How Can I prevent that?

Do I have to add rules in all my resolvers for all nested queries?

related Documentation:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/guides/security.html
https://www.howtographql.com/advanced/4-security/
https://blog.apollographql.com/securing-your-graphql-api-from-malicious-queries-16130a324a6b
https://www.prisma.io/forum/t/graphql-security-protect-nested-data/4519

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One arguably more elegant solution is to utilize Row Level Security (RLS) to control what data any particular user has access to. While that approach adds some complexity, it's particularly appealing if your API is accessed by users with different roles that have different levels of access. This is actually how [postgraphile](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/) handles authentication.

You can also potentially use schema directives to keep things DRY and apply some general access logic to a set of individual fields. Apollo's docs actually have [an example of doing just that](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/creating-directives.html).

Outside of that, yes, your resolvers will need to be context-aware and include logic to limit the data you're exposing.

It's important to point out that these sort of concerns also go back to good schema design in the first place. For example, just because a relationship exists doesn't mean it needs to (or should be) exposed to the client. An order may include one or more products, and if the client needs to display order history, it makes sense to expose a `products` fields on the `Order` type. On the other hand, does the client actually need to know all the orders for a given Product?

Similarly, if we have a `users` field on `Order`, outside of any user-specific context, such a field would naturally only reflect the users (most likely just the one user) associated with the order. Returning all users as a field on a single order makes no sense. Because of GraphQL's top-down nature, a field is usually going to only be limited to the context of its parent. As a result, it's possible to only have to worry about user context at the root level.

A different, arbitrary example:

```
query MyOrders {
  orders { # check context for user and limit results to just the logged in user
    user { # user will be based on parent (the order), no need to check context
      orders { # orders will be based on parent (the user), no need to check context  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With sound schema design, the resolvers for other types' fields don't necessarily need to do any additional context checking.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how RLS should be implemented? If I understand correctly this should be done on the database level, does it mean you then have to various connections to your database depending on the user (authorization-)group? 

2nd link on apollo's documentation is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes, but not at every level for nesting.

With any request you have the user (or lack of user) and the path into the graph.  This is the exact same for restful type requests where you have to authorize the request.  It is harder though b/c the resolvers can be added anywhere.

Probably the best talk on how facebook handles this is here https://blog.apollographql.com/graphql-at-facebook-by-dan-schafer-38d65ef075af

The gist is they have a function that is responsible for fetching and authorizing that the resolvers use.